# Solution for by mistakenly deleting var folder from home directory

Tags: 12.04, boot

I am new to Ubuntu. I am failing to start Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit...

I was trying to move one of my files from one place to another and by mistake I deleted the `var` folder using `sudo rm -R /var` folder from the home directory. I tried restarting my laptop and then I ended up at [this](http://postimg.org/image/fiokwnqhb/). The image is taken from my cell phone which is of low quality.

I tried my best to figure this out, but failed.

Please help me out in this.

Thanks...

Comment: your picture is of the  CLI login screen.

Comment: This may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/332246/what-to-do-if-you-removed-usr-local/332256#332256

Comment: Reinstall without formatting is the quickest method.

Comment: How do i do it ?? Please give me any tutorial for the same..

Answer (score 2):

The [/var directory](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/var.html) is the place where the system writes data during the course of its operation. It's specific for each computer and contains variable data like system logging files, mail and printer spool directories, and transient and temporary files.

You got how important it is, so re-installation would be the solution once you have backed up your files.

Good luck buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Re-install 12.04 your user files shouldn't be afftected but it's always a good idea to have a backup in case of hardware failure during the process.

Source:

[Guide on upgrading Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04 (troubleshoot queries)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336237/guide-on-upgrading-ubuntu-11-10-to-12-04-troubleshoot-queries/336281#336281)